# how to call javascript variable in HTML form textfield

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script, the idea is to select from the drop down list and then display the selected value in a text field (HTML Form).
When i make the selection, I do not get the value displayed in the text field, please help.

```
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
    <option value="BMW">BMW
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<input type="text" id="demo" onload="myFunction()" >



<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The element with `id="demo"` is hidden.

Comment: You commented out your `demo` element...

Comment: I had commented it out to call the variable in the *<input* element

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment `<!--<p id="demo"></p>-->` and it works fine.

```js
  function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
```

```html
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
    <option value="BMW">BMW
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I had commented it out to call the variable in the <input element. I have edited my question to show exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use, the following script that is in jquery to do this job,,

```
    $(function(){
    var select_value = $('#mySelect').find(":selected").val();
     $("#demo").text(select_value);
     });
```

//in javascript, this might work

```
function myFunction() {

    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").find(":selected").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("id_of_text_field_input").value = x;

}
```

Comment: This works, but in a paragraph element, but i want it to be displayed in a textfield

Comment: you can use following code for this job,                                                                              function myFunction() {

    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").find(":selected").value;
    document.getElementById("id_of_text_field_input").value = x;

}

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
    <option value="BMW">BMW
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>


<p id="demo"></p>
<!--<p id="demo"></p>-->



<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }

</script>
```

You had not created a text field or any other element with the id "demo".

Comment: I have this line right after the closing tag of script, *<input type="text" id="demo" value="">*